# Error in event handler for (unknown): ReferenceError: result is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, googlevis

I am developing with Javascript and Google Charts, and while testing code I've been noticing that I always receive this error in the Google Developers Console:

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): ReferenceError: result is not defined
at updateURLRegexp (chrome-extension://cgllkjmdafllcidaehjejjhpfkmanmka/tmn_search.js:489:16)
at notifyUserSearch (chrome-extension://cgllkjmdafllcidaehjejjhpfkmanmka/tmn_search.js:616:9)
at chrome-extension://cgllkjmdafllcidaehjejjhpfkmanmka/tmn_search.js:681:25handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8exports.handle @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:100EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:376EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:393target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @     extensions::utils:94dispatchOnMessage @ extensions::messaging:310
    WorldHomicideCountAndRate.html:197 Region: Americas
    SubRegions: 98
    WorldHomicideCountAndRate.html:220 0
    WorldHomicideCountAndRate.html:166 SubRegion: Caribbean
    Countries: 46
    WorldHomicideCountAndRate.html:220 2
```

why? Is it something I'm doing or it can't be fixed?

> CODE I would post snippets of code but I'm not sure which part is creating the issue:

You can view the whole code:

http://ltw1556.web.cs.unibo.it/WorldHomicideCountAndRate.html

Comment: We'd need to see the code and how you test it.

Comment: here is the whole code: http://ltw1556.web.cs.unibo.it/WorldHomicideCountAndRate.html 

probably it's better for testing